# Are there any official ways to write an Immediately Invoked Function Expression?

Tags: c#

Something like this:

```
var myObject = new MyClass()
{
    x = " ".Select(y =>
    {
        //Do stuff..
        if (2 + 2 == 5)
            return "I like cookies";
        else if (2 + 2 == 3)
            return "I like muffins";
        //More conditions...
        else
            return "I'm a bitter old man";
    })
};
```

I realize Select is not intended to be used this way. But yeah, what are some other ways to do the same thing?

Comment: If it's too long, put it in a function?

Comment: `what are some other ways to do the same thing?` What are you trying to do? Where is the property?

Comment: I wouldn't use return in a select statement for a start (Plus basic mathematics states you are a bitter old man)

Comment: It's for argument's sake.

Comment: @Sayse I said as much in the question. I'm trying to find a proper equivalent to it.

Comment: You may get away with using a ternary operator but I don't like encouraging bad code `condition1 ? "cookies" : condition2 ? "muffins" : "bitter"`

Comment: @Sayse a ternary operator is exactly what I was trying to avoid xD

Comment: You should be avoiding it altogether, a collection of bitter old men has no relevance to the original collection

Comment: Note that your `Select()` code won't actually work.

Comment: Did you forget `.Single()`? Actually, this is almost idiomatic and better than what I was originally thinking of.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm surprised no one's mentioned this yet, but you could use the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329.aspx) class:

```
var myObject = new MyClass()
{
    x = new Lazy<string>(() =>
    {
        //Do stuff..
        if (2 + 2 == 5)
            return "I like cookies";
        else if (2 + 2 == 3)
            return "I like muffins";
        //More conditions...
        else
            return "I'm a bitter old man";
    }).Value // <-- Evaluate the function here
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid having to specify the return type anywhere (as you do with `new Lazy<string>` because constructors do not support type inference), you can implement a simple generic method like this:

```
public static T Eval<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return func();
}
```

And then you can call like this:

```
var myObject = new MyClass()
{
    x = Eval(() =>
    {
        //Do stuff..
        if (2 + 2 == 5)
            return "I like cookies";
        else if (2 + 2 == 3)
            return "I like muffins";
        //More conditions...
        else
            return "I'm a bitter old man";
    })
};
```

---

**Update**: C#7 introduces [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). These are not *really* IFFEs, but they may solve a variety of related issues. For example:

```
var myObject = new MyClass()
{
    x = GetX()
};

string GetX() {
    //Do stuff..
    if (2 + 2 == 5)
        return "I like cookies";
    else if (2 + 2 == 3)
        return "I like muffins";
    //More conditions...
    else
        return "I'm a bitter old man";
}
```

The key here is that `GetX` can be declared within the same method as `myObject` share the same scope as it.

Comment: This is perfect. It makes sense, it doesn't have a messy amount of parenthesizes and there is no casting going on in there.

Answer (score 28):

For real code make it a function... For entertainment purposes C# equivalent of [JavaScript IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) is more direct than `Select`:

```
var myObject = new MyClass()
{
   x =((Func<int>)(() => {return 2;}))(),...
```

Comment: I just used this for populating some test data.

Comment: you can use `new` to make it look a little nicer. `x = new Func<int>(() => 2)()`. It just unfortunately can't be implicitly typed.

Comment: actually you could make it implicitly typed with a static method. `x = Func.Create(() => 2)();`

Comment: the above comment `Func.Create` is not built by default in dotnet. Have to refer @DaveCousineau 's other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52572453/273743

Answer (score 6):

Here is what my coworker came up with:

```
var myObject = new { 
    x = new Func<int>(() => {return 2;})() 
};
```

Note that this is based Alexei's answer.

Comment: @DanielGimenez it does compile. I just ran it on LinqPad. It also does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It compiles and runs on my machine, on both LinqPad and visual studio. Yes, this is based on Alexi's answer.

Comment: Okay.  I see my mistake, you had string in your original post, but you changed it to an int here.

Comment: Much more concise than `((Func<int>)(() => 2))()`!

Comment: @binki How do you mean "more concise"? If anything, it's more code and therefore more verbose, no?

Comment: @MEMark I think of it as less busy because it has fewer parentheses to keep track of. That makes it more readable to me. Checking back, I guess that the four parentheses saved matches the four characters lost by requiring `new `. So `new Func<int>(() => 2)()` and `((Func<int>)(() => 2))()` are both exactly 24 characters long. I still think that `new ` syntax is clearer than the syntax which uses two additional pairs of parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

It's can be tricky to get an implicitly typed delegate, but it works if you write your own static methods for it.

You can create an implicitly typed function like this:

```
public static class Func {
   public static Func<T> Create<T>(
      Func<T> func
   ) =>
     func;       
}

...

var x = Func.Create(() => "result")();
Assert.AreEqual("result", x);

var x = Func.Create(() => {
   // complex logic to create a value
})();
```

And you can also write one to immediately evaluate a function and then you don't need to do it manually:

```
public static class Func {
   public static T Eval<T>(
      Func<T> func
   ) =>
      func();
}

...

var x = Func.Eval(() => 5);
Assert.AreEqual(5, x);
```

Comment: exactly, and you can add multiple overloads with different count of generic arguments

Comment: This is IMO the cleanest option. Note that you could execute the delegate within the `Create` method, and save the extra parentheses. I usually name this method [`IIFE`](https://github.com/zspitz/ZSpitz.Util/blob/06d879c0f90384175aa65dccabd3db6309c25525/ZSpitz.Util/Functions.cs#L325), and do precisely that; I reference it with `using static` so the call ends up looking like this: `IIFE(() => /* produce value here */);`.

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa The point of an IIFE is to return a single value without any parameters -- "**immediately executing** function expression. There isn't really any need for multiple overloads.

Comment: @ZevSpitz in `Func<...Args, TOut>`, the first type parameters are used as input arguments so overloads will be ok when your function accepts parameters. For example: `Func.Create((int x, int y) => x + y)(myVar1, myVar2)` it would require you to define this overload: `public static Func<TOut> Create<T0, T1, TOut>(Func<T0,T1,TOut> pFunc) => pFunc`

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa But you could simply use the variables inside the body of the function: `IIFE(() => myVar1 + myVar2)`, because you're invoking it right away. What do you gain by having an immediately invoked function that you have to pass parameters into?

Comment: in the IIFE case nothing, but when creating a function that is reusable yes

Answer (score 4):

While certainly *not* "official", you *could* use optional named parameters in the constructor or a separate factory/builder method:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string x { get; private set; }

   public MyClass(Func<string> x = null)
    {
        if (x != null)
            this.x = x();
    }
}
```

with usage like:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(
        x: () =>
            {
                //Do stuff..
                if (2 + 2 == 5)
                    return "I like cookies";
                else if (2 + 2 == 3)
                    return "I like muffins";
                //More conditions...
                else
                    return "I'm a bitter old man";
            }
    );

    Console.WriteLine(myClass.x); //"I'm a bitter old man"
```

So, it's not the *exact* syntax you were asking for, but pretty close and skips the LINQ weirdness.

That said, I don't *like* it. Just offering it as food for thought. :)

---

EDIT: I figured I'd add a factory method style since it's plausible you're using this on a class that you can't (or don't want to) change its constructor:

```
public static class MyFactory
{
    public static MyClass CreateMyClass(Func<string> x = null)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass()

        if (x != null)
                myClass.x = x();

        return myClass;
    }
}
```

With similar usage (just calling a factory method instead):

```
var myClass = MyFactory.CreateMyClass(
    x: () =>
        {
            //Do stuff..
            if (2 + 2 == 5)
                return "I like cookies";
            else if (2 + 2 == 3)
                return "I like muffins";
            //More conditions...
            else
                return "I'm a bitter old man";
        }
);
```

---

EDIT: And hey, while we're at it. Why not go off the deep end and do it with a separate builder and *abuse* implicit operators!

```
public class MyClassBuilder
{
    public Func<string> x { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyClass(MyClassBuilder builder)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();

        if (builder.x != null)
            myClass.x = builder.x();

        return myClass;
    }
}
```

With usage like:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClassBuilder
{
    x = () =>
        {
            //Do stuff..
            if (2 + 2 == 5)
                return "I like cookies";
            else if (2 + 2 == 3)
                return "I like muffins";
            //More conditions...
            else
                return "I'm a bitter old man";
        }
};
```

So now the syntax is *identical*, *except* you have to explicitly type your instance instead of using `var`.

Comment: While the first example is interesting it isn't what the asker wanted.  The second example is the cleanest I've seen, and gets the point.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite answering the question but ... one reason I wanted IIFE in C# was to give better meaning to a function being called on an object. In this example I wanted to give meaning as to what the 'Click' method does in a particular context within test code (and I do not like comments).

Before ...

```
lastLine.Click(); //click to begin editing line
```

After ...

```
Action<IWebElement> clickToStartEditing = line => line.Click();
clickToStartEditing(lastLine);
```

Later I discovered I could simply create a new method with another name ...

```
Action clickToStartEditing = lastLine.Click;
clickToStartEditing(lastLine);
```

Finally simply naming the variable in a better way can better solve the issue (for me)

```
lastLineForEditing.Click();
```

This solved an IIFE issue for me, to give meaning to the method name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
global using static System.IIFE;

namespace System {
  public static class IIFE {
    public static T Scope<T>(Func<T> f) => f();
  }
}
```

And then:

```
var x = Scope(() => {
  var t1 = getVal();
  vat t2 = getVal2();
  return t1+t2;
});
```

The advantage of IIFE here is that t1 and t2 do not pollute the outside scope