# What is the syntax for adding anonymous tasks to this list?

Tags: c#

I have some code that looks like this:

```
async void MyMethod()
{
   var client = new HttpClient();

   var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

   for (int id = 1; id <= 10; id++)
   {
      tasks.Add(GetValue(client, id));
   }  

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

async Task<string> GetValue(HttpClient client, int id)
{
   var response = await client.GetAsync($"http://example.com?id={id}");

   // Do something else here so that this task can't be condensed to a 
   // single line of code
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("something");

   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

What is the syntax to add anonymous tasks to `tasks` without the use of the `GetValue` method?  I want to do something like the code below, but I can't figure out the syntax to return a `Task<string>` from my anonymous method (this code gives me a compilation error `Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type Func<string>`):

```
for (int id = 1; id <= 10; id++)
{
    tasks.Add(new Task<string>(async () =>
    {
       var response = await client.GetAsync($"http://example.com?id={id}");

       // Do something else here so that this task can't be condensed to a 
       // single line of code
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("something");

       return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }));
}
```

Comment: Obviously in case shown you just make it into single statement `tasks.Add((await client.GetAsync($"http://example.com?id={1}")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` but you probably asking for something else...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes you're right, I'm looking for a way to do it if the task is not something that can be written in a single line of code.

Comment: @BenRubin If you can't write it in a single line it's almost certainly *worth* putting it in a named method, even if it's a local method.

Comment: I edited my original question to reflect a more complicated task.

Comment: As @Servy pointed out the way "single line" version looks like is very confusing and I'd strongly advice against it... But here is what you are asking about - C# IIFE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279520/are-there-any-official-ways-to-write-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression

Comment: `// Do something else here so that this task can't be condensed to a 
   // single line of code` Is it an option to put that code inside the loop? And use `Enumerable.Range().Select().ToList()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you execute a delegate is pretty simple, you just invoke it.

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return func();
}
```

---

```
for (int id = 1; id <= 10; id++)
{
    tasks.Add(Execute(async () =>
    {
       var response = await client.GetAsync($"http://example.com?id={id}");
       return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }));
}
```