# Trying to convert dictionary results to tuples using same dictionary keys to filter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, .net-6.0

I have a query that will give the results in the dictionary `<Guid, List<Energy>>`, and then I filter the dictionary results by using the other dictionary key, which is working fine.

Now I would like to apply this filtering right after dictionary results in a single statement, and the result would be tuples.

Below is the query for where I am getting results in the form of a dictionary

```
        var energiesByBenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId = BenchmarkingModeledEnergyItems
            ?.GroupBy(o => o.BenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId)
            .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, 
                          o => o.Select(p => new Energy
                          {
                              Unit = energyUnitById[p.Energy.UnitId],
                              Scalar = p.Energy.Scalar
                          }).ToList());
```

and below is where I am filtering the dictionary results with other dictionaries and getting the results

```
List<Energy> proposedEnergies = null;
List<Energy> baselineEnergies = null;
energiesByBenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId?.TryGetValue(benchmarkingEnergyModelTypeIdByName["Proposed"], out proposedEnergies);
energiesByBenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId?.TryGetValue(benchmarkingEnergyModelTypeIdByName["Baseline"], out baselineEnergies);
```

Now would like to get these from the above query, and the sample output looks like the below.

```
var (proposedEnergies, baselineEnergies) = BenchmarkingModeledEnergyItems
                                           ?.GroupBy(o => o.BenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId)
                                            ......
```

I am trying to figure out how to convert dictionary results to tuples, but I couldn't figure out how to filter the results with the key.

```
var (proposedEnergies, baselineEnergies) = BenchmarkingModeledEnergyItems
            ?.GroupBy(o => o.BenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId)
            .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, 
                          o => o.Select(p => new Energy
                          {
                              Unit = energyUnitById[p.Energy.UnitId],
                              Scalar = p.Energy.Scalar
                          }).ToList())
             .Select(a => new Tuple<List<Energy>, List<Energy>>()); // here need to filter out the results and add to the tuples
```

Could anyone suggest any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'm quite confused what you want as result... It is possible that you want to use result multiple times in a single statement without explicitly creating a variable for it purely for entertainment purposes (aka "code golf") - see if IIFE is what you are after - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279520/are-there-any-official-ways-to-write-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry, it's not for entertainment purposes, and I do not want to filter the results separately and looking for a way that gets tuples as results out of that LINQ statement

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, could you please suggest any ideas on the same

Comment: The desired end result is a `Tuple` that has two items, each of type `List<Energy>`?  Is that right?

Comment: Is this LINQ statement against a DB? Is that why you want it to be done all in a single LINQ statement?

Comment: Are the only two IDs "Proposed" and "Baseline"?

Comment: @AnnL. That is against Icollection group

Comment: This question would benefit greatly from having sample data, as valid C# code, a [mcve] for the current working code, and the desired output of the sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the following might meet your needs. See what you think.

```
var proposedModelType = benchmarkingEnergyModelTypeIdByName["Proposed"];
var baselineModelType = benchmarkingEnergyModelTypeIdByName["Baseline"];

var (proposedEnergies, baselineEnergies) = new Tuple<List<Energy>, List<Energy>>( 
            // Query BMEI, filtering by "Proposed" ModelTypeId
            BenchmarkingModeledEnergyItems
                .Where(o => o.BenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId == proposedModelType)
                // Make the new "Energy" items.
                .Select(p => new Energy
                          {
                              Unit = energyUnitById[p.Energy.UnitId],
                              Scalar = p.Energy.Scalar
                          })
                .ToList(),
            // Query BMEI, filtering by "Baseline" Model Type ID
            BenchmarkingModeledEnergyItems
                .Where(e => e.BenchmarkingEnergyModelTypeId == baselineModelType)
                // Make the new "Energy" items.
                .Select(p => new Energy
                          {
                              Unit = energyUnitById[p.Energy.UnitId],
                              Scalar = p.Energy.Scalar
                          })
                .ToList()
);
```

But your original version is probably the simplest solution!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Can we combine those two queries where we are filtering based on Id

Comment: Well, the short answer is "probably not", unless you introduce an intermediate variable (to hold the `Where` clause output) and reference it twice (once for each of the items in the `Tuple`.)

Comment: However, I could write an extension method that would do this for you, which would hide the implementation. It would be against your original `IGrouping` and would have a signature something like `ToTuple(modelTypeId typeId1, modelTypeId typeId2)`. Would that help you?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you don't want to use an intermediate variable, such as your dictionary, as a step along the way to creating your tuple. I can understand not wanting to hit your original data source more than once, but you're doing _two_ expression evaluations/assignments, one for each item in the tuple. That requires hitting _something_ twice, whether it's an intermediate result (the dictionary) or the original data source.